# My repeater does not render in the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I created a repeater and can not render it. When we inspect the object, it does not appear. I took the code above it , called analyze registration data and repeat after the repeater and can not see , but the repeater not. What could be wrong ? Below the code from analyze registration data :

```
<div class="boxAprovacao">
        <h2>Analisar dados cadastrais</h2>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCdPendencia" runat="server" />
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblIcAprovado" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Aprovar" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Reprovar" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>     
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtParecerDadosCadastrais" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" CssClass="parecerAnalista" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCdUsuario" runat="server" />

        <asp:Repeater ID="rptHistoricoAnalises" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptHistoricoAnalises_ItemDataBound">
            <HeaderTemplate>
            <h3>Histórico de análises</h3>
            <dl>    
            </HeaderTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
            <dt>
                Por:
                <asp:Label Text="ANA LUCIA ALVES MARTINS" ID="lblHistAnaNmAnalista" runat="server" /><br />
                Em: <asp:Label Text="03/12/2014" ID="lblHistAnaData" runat="server" /> - <asp:Label Text="10:19" ID="lblHistAnaHorario" runat="server" />
            </dt>
            <dd>
                <asp:Label Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque bibendum diam augue, ut varius lectus luctus a. Sed finibus fringilla nibh. Quisque orci erat, iaculis quis neque vitae, maximus vehicula tortor. Praesent luctus venenatis venenatis. Nullam non lacus orci. Vivamus convallis hendrerit urna, vel facilisis sapien semper non." ID="lblHistAnaParacerAnalista" runat="server" />
            </dd>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <FooterTemplate>
            </dl>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

If I run a method and ItemTemplate I do this : `< td> < asp: Label ID = " lblValorPedido " runat = "server" Text = '< % # Eval ( " VlCompra ")% > ' /> < / td>` for example , since the repeater understands that this is my DataSource ?

**EDIT1**

I cannot to post code behind because i'm not working in this company. I left that company in Fev/2017. I'd like to improve my post, but is not possible. I still am ban in this site and i don't know what to do.

Comment: May we have some code-behind, please?

Comment: Specifically, where are you binding the data to the repeater?

Comment: On a side note, you should probably just use data-binding markup to bind fields of the bound items to controls rather than applying the data in each item to that item's template in a row-data-bound method.

Comment: @pnet Then you're not binding any data to the repeater.

Comment: Ok, Servy, I understood. Literal values ​​as it is not going to work , right?

Comment: If you want to reply to someone, use the @mason syntax. That way we will get notified.

Comment: If I run a method and ItemTemplate I do this : < td> < asp: Label ID = " lblValorPedido " runat = "server" Text = '< % # Eval ( " VlCompra ")% > ' /> < / td> for example , since the repeater understands that this is my DataSource ?

Comment: @pnet Your last comment is unclear. Once you hook up the data source properly as shown in my answer, then you can use Eval to inject values into the resulting HTML from the data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either set the [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx) of the [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.110).aspx), then call [DataBind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1th73f0(v=vs.110).aspx) on it, or hook the repeater up to some data source control through [DataSourceID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.datasourceid(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute. Since you haven't done that, there's nothing for it to repeat over, and therefore no HTML is generated.

---

Code behind, showing the DataSource/DataBind method. Notice I'm checking to make sure it's not a postback, since ViewState will maintain the data between postbacks and I don't need to refetch the data.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
         rptHistoricoAnalises.DataSource = MyDataLayer.GetData();
         rptHistoricoAnalises.DataBind();
    }
}
```

---

As I mentioned, the other method is using a data source control.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" id="MyDataSource" connectionstring="your connection string here" selectcommand="your select command here" />
<asp:Repeater ID="rptHistoricoAnalises" DataSourceID="MyDataSource" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptHistoricoAnalises_ItemDataBound">
```